# How to set int value from JSONObject to bean?

Tags: json

```
bean.setR_slno((long)jsonObject.get("r_slno").intValue());
```

Iam trying to set my int value in bean from the int value i get from JsonObject, how that can be done?

Comment: so what you're basically ask is how to get get an interger of a json object, am I getting it right ? 
what json lib are u using ? 
why are you casting to long if you want an int ?

Comment: yes i want to get an int of a json object,                              bean.setR_slno(jsonObject.get("r_slno"));        iam using simple json jar

Comment: okay try this then: `((Long)jsonObject.get("r_slno")).intValue()`.
Seems like you've missed the brackets around the `obj.get()`

Comment: Any other methods?

Comment: doesn't it work ? make sure you're casting to the wrapper class Long not  to the primitive data typ long